I want to prove that: Every finite multiplicative subgroup ${G}$ of field ${F}$ is cyclic.
I do agree with this proof:
If ${G}$ is not cyclic,
then ${\mathbb{Z}_p \times\mathbb{Z}_p}$ can be embedded in ${G}$
so that ${x^p=1}$ has ${p^2}$ roots (contradiction).
And here is my proof:
$(1,1), (p-1,p-1) \in \mathbb{Z}_p \times\mathbb{Z}_p.\ (1,1)+(p-1,p-1)=(0,0)$. $G$ has zero divisors (contradiction).
My professor said that we are considering ${\mathbb{Z}_p \times\mathbb{Z}_p}$
as multiplicative group. Therefore, my proof is not valid. However, in my opinion,
${\mathbb{Z}_p \times\mathbb{Z}_p}$ is not multiplicative group. Because ${(0,0)}$ has no inverse. If we were considering ${\mathbb{Z}_p^\times \times\mathbb{Z}_p^\times}$, then ${x^p=1}$ has ${(p-1)^2}$ roots.
Can you explain why my proof is wrong?
I think considering ${\mathbb{Z}_p \times\mathbb{Z}_p}$ as an additive group makes sense because, when we found that ${\mathbb{Z}_p \times\mathbb{Z}_p}$, can be embedded in G, we used the Fundamental theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian group, which refers to an additive group.

Your argument makes no sense. The copy of $Z_p\times Z_p$ you are positing in your field $F$ is in the multiplicative group of nonzero elements, so the element $(0,0)$ of that group maps to the multiplicative identity of $F$. You are showing that the image of $(1,1)$ times the image of $(p-1,p-1)$ is the image of $(0,0)$, i.e., $1_F$, not $0_F$.

"we used the Fundamental theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian group, which refers to an additive group" hmmm this theorem only tells you that a finitely generated abelian group is isomorphic to some direct sum of the form
$\mathbb{Z}^n \oplus \mathbb{Z}{k_1}\oplus \dots \oplus \mathbb{Z}{k_u}$.
Here your group $G$ is a subgroup of the multiplicative group $F^*$. Saying that $\Bbb Z_p\times\Bbb Z_p$ can be embedded in $G$ only means that there exists an injective group homomorphism from $(\Bbb Z_p\times\Bbb Z_p,+)$ to $(G,\cdot)$.

Like the homomorphism $\Bbb Z_n\to\Bbb C^*,k\mapsto e^{i2k\pi/n}$.

Thank you. I completely understand.

The question was about a solution verification, and you two verified the solution, thus answering the question. But comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

The only difference between an additive and a multiplicative group is that we use "$+$" instead of "$\cdot$" as symbol for the group operation :)

"we used the Fundamental theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian group, which refers to an additive group" hmmm this theorem only tells you that a finitely generated abelian group is isomorphic to some direct sum of the form $\Bbb Z^n\oplus\Bbb Z_{k_1}\oplus\dots\oplus\Bbb Z_{k_u}$. Here your group $G$ is a subgroup of the multiplicative group $F^*$. Saying that $\Bbb Z_p\times\Bbb Z_p$ can be embedded in $G$ only means that there exists an injective group homomorphism from $(\Bbb Z_p\times\Bbb Z_p,+)$ to $(G,⋅)$, like the homomorphism $\Bbb Z_n\to\Bbb C^*,k\mapsto e^{i2k\pi/n}$.
